# electron pdf window doesnt work after build

Tags: electron

I'm trying to open pdf in electron app with electron-pdf-window. Its working fine before build but when i build app as installer .exe file for windows and install exe file on windows 8.1 , its not showing pdf window, i am using it through renderer process on click of anchor. Any ideas?
here is my code

```
   function pdfWindow() {
    const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
    const PDFWindow = require('electron-pdf-window')
    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 800 })
    PDFWindow.addSupport(win)
    win.loadURL('http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf')
}
```

and i am calling this function on click of anchor tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest Electron 1.8 or newer, it has built in PDF support in `BrowserWindow`'s and `<webview>` tags. You just have to ensure plugins are enabled:

#### `BrowserWindow`

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1024,
  height: 800,
  webPreferences: {
    plugins: true
  }
});

window.loadURL('path/to/file.pdf');
```

#### `<webview>` Tag

```
<webview src="path/to/file.pdf" plugins></webview>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for solution.

Comment: One more question. If I have lets say 10 pdf's, and I want for each to open in new window, do I have to write this entire code for each pdf but with different URL, or is there some code that opens all pdf's in new window?